# AngularJS: module.exports in karma test: module not defined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

I'm trying to write an external module to handle my service for my karma test using `module.exports` but I keep getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Here is my karma.conf.js file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Nov 07 2014 11:32:23 GMT-0600 (CST)

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'tests/unit/*.js',
  'tests/unit/*.spec.js',
  'tests/unit/**/*.js'

],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
});
};
```

And my module looks like this:

```
var devSrv = (function(){
    return{
       get: 'abc'
    }
}());
module.exports = devSrv;
```

As a side note, I've had this issue using protractor as well.